# Height div and image

Tags: php, jquery

i have a problem with a div height. I have an image in a left div "image_view" and the height of this div is dinamically based on image.
On the right side I have a div with some informations. This div must have the same height of the image_view div. how can I do it?
This is my code now.

```
<div id="image_view">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/images/'.$nome_immagine; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="info_image" style="height:<?php echo $altezza.'px'; ?>">
   content of this div
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$('#info_image').css("height", $("#image_view").height());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can get the image height with [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and assign it to the `info_image` element.

```
<?php 
$imagePath = base_url().'upload/images/'.$nome_immagine;
$size = getimagesize($imagePath);
?>

<div id="image_view">
    <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="info_image" style="height:<?php echo $size[1].'px'; ?>">
   content of this div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution without JavaScript

You can restructure your HTML, to force the `<div>`'s the same height as the image:

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-info-container">
   <div id="image-info">
       <div id="image">
           <img src="" />
       </div>
       <div id="info">
           info here
       </div>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#image-info {
    width: 600px;
    background:#eeeeee;
}

#info {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}

#image {
   float: left;
   background: #f0e;
   width: 400px;
}

#image img {
   height: 500px; 
}
​
```

This will force the `#image-info-area` to become same height as the image, and you will be able style the `<div>`'s anyway you want.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmdYL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `height()` function:

```
$('#info_image').height($('#image_view').height());
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaHaB/)